# Rotate animation continuously with specific acceleration

Tags: android

I have an imageView on which I would like to perform a rotation animation using a specific acceleration.

Please first check this link: https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/

What I would like to achieve is a spinner animation similar to the second one at the second row of the page, more precisely this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZCYy.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's in fact an easy way to achieve this animation, which is using a `FastOutSlowInInterpolator` like so:

```
val rotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(
    0f, 360f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
)

rotateAnimation.interpolator = FastOutSlowInInterpolator()
rotateAnimation.duration = 1000
rotateAnimation.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE

spinner.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is an easy way to do this sort of thing without having to create keyframes and interpolating between them.

that being said, if you're not set on design you could take a look at [this library](https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit) that seems to have a few nice android spinners already built in.  Even if you are set on design, this library may be a good place to start.

You could also take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation) part of the android documentation